# How to update data of a RecyclerView that is inside a composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `RecyclerView` that is created and added to my compose layout through the `AndroidView` function.

```
@Composable
fun MyView(data: State<List<Item>>) {
   ...
   AndroidView(factory = { context ->
        RecyclerView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = ItemListAdapter().also { it.submitList(data.value) }
        }
    })
}
```

I used `RecyclerView` instead of `LazyColumn` because I want to have add and remove animations which is not yet supported by `LazyColumn` and I achieve that with the RecyclerView through the use of `DiffUtil`

Now, every time my `data` changes, the view is recomposed, thus the RecyclerView is recreated and the animations are not showed.

What is the best way in which I can achieve this? Should I just pass a LiveData then observe it on the RecyclerView's Adapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `update` callback, it gets called on each recomposition:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        RecyclerView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = ItemListAdapter().also { it.submitList().value }
        }
    },
    update = { recyclerView ->

    }
)
```

Not sure why you're saying that "RecyclerView is recreated" on each recomposition, it shouldn't be like that. I've tested and only `update = {` gets called on recomposition